# Why does the PODS wordpress plugin is not return true when checking -> exists() against a valid POD?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the **PODS plugin** for custom post types within WordPress.

The problem I've got is in the
`if ($mypod->exists() ){` line - I've hard coded the $user_id and $id - to values that definitely exist in the database - 100% checked.

The code below gets past the `if ( false !== $mypod)` check - but then when I go to "exists" that check fails and it goes to "doesn't exist".

Is there a problem with my `$params` definition, or is it in my inderstanding of the "exists()" check?

Thanks, Mark

```
$user_id=2;
$id=720;
$params = [
    'where'   => 't.ID = ' . $id  . ' and t.post_author = ' . $user_id
];
$mypod = pods( 'tftracker', $params);
// Check if the pod is valid.
if ( false !== $mypod ) {
    // Check if the pod item exists.
    if ($mypod->exists() ){
        echo 'exists';
        $fields = array( 'measure_description', 'unit_type', 'latest_result', 'result_date' );
        // Output an edit form with all fields
        echo $mypod->form( $fields );
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'doesn\'t exist';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `if ( false !== $mypod )` to `if ( $mypod )`. It's possible the `pods()` function returns null rather than false as a failure result.

Comment: Hi - thank you for the suggestion.  I tried that, and it didn't work either.  It actually gets past the if (false !== $mypod) line - it's if($mypod->exists()) line that seems to return false.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the strict option:

https://docs.pods.io/code/pods/